# SQL Query MAX with SUm

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table where i have ID,matchid,point1,point2. I need to get the ID which has the maximum points but the problem i am facing is i need find max record depending on sum of both (point1+point), I have no idea how I can get the max with the combination of 2 columns i have tried query such as,

```
SELECT MAX(column1+column2) FROM table

MAX(SUM(column1,column2)) FROM table
```

but nothing works I am using Ms:Access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return more than one answer if more than one sum=max:

```
SELECT ID FROM Table1 
WHERE ([Field1]+[Field2])=(
    SELECT Max([Field1]+[Field2]) AS Expr1
    FROM Table1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery e.g.

```
select id from table where point1+point2 = (select max(point1+point2) from table)
```

Note that this will return multiple rows if more than one record has the same maximum points.